# Firestore relation type in securty rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I use a reference type in security rules to refer to a field in the external document? By external I mean not the current document to which the firestore rule is being applied. I couldn't seem to find any documentation. I tried a few options but with 10 minute propagation its slightly laborious. The 10 minute propogation is how long it takes for firestore rules to update in the worst case.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you provide a use case and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to accomplish? We don't know what an *external object* is or why it would have fields and we really don't know what or why there's a *10 minute propegation*. Perhaps including a snippet of your Firebase structure and current rules would help as well.

Comment: Do my edits help. The terminology should be clearer.